# Laravel + blade. Где взялась переменная?

Tags: laravel, blade

Есть сайт на laravel 5.7. Мне нужно изменить некоторые функции. 
Есть 3 файла: master, edit, form. Для наглядности я удалил весь лишний код.

master.blade.php:

```
@yield("content")
```

edit.blade.php:

```
@section('content')
    @include('admin.inventory._form')
@endsection
```

_form.blade.php:

```
@php dd( get_defined_vars()) @endphp
```

на экран выводится:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но если попытаться вывести переменные в edit.blade.php или создать _test.blade.php то коллекций нет.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как это возможно?

Где берутся эти коллекции, если в документации написано: "Все переменные, доступные родительскому шаблону, будут доступны и включаемому шаблону", но в родительском этих переменных нет?

Comment: может быть это - https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/views#view-composers

Comment: нет, поскольку вью не загружается в случае этого теста. На всякий случай очистил весь код оставив лишь 
@section('content')
        @include('admin.inventory._form')
@endsection

Ситуация не меняется

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Спустя несколько часов курения доки нашел ответ на свой вопрос. 
https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/views#view-composers